# Electron Multi-monitor bug with vibrancy/transparency on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: javascript, html, macos, electron, uivibrancyeffect

I've noticed what appears to be a bug with the vibrancy effects in Electron, running on MacOS Big Sur...

Here's what my window looks like when it first loads:

[image]

Here's what it looks like if I drag it to another screen and back again, without releasing the mouse:

[image]

Here's what it looks like if I drag it to another screen, release the mouse, and then drag it back again:

[image]

Here's how I've set up my `BrowserWindow`:

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    darkTheme: true,
    frame: false,
    roundedCorners: true,
    transparent: true,
    vibrancy: 'fullscreen-ui',
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    minWidth: 640,
    minHeight: 480
})
```

And finally, here's the markup, so you can see how/why there's a draggable header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        header {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 38px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -webkit-app-region: drag;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>

    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Aside from "it's a bug", are there any ideas as to why the Window loses its rounded edges and drop shadow when it's dragged to another screen. If this is a bug in the way I've set up the code, rather than in Electron, how do I fix this?

Comment: Try creating an issue in [Electron's GitHub repo](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues)